# Symfony2: Execute some code after every action

Tags: php, symfony

I recently started a project in Symfony2 and I need to run some methods before and after every action to avoid code redundancy (like preDispatch/postDispatch from Zend Framework and PreExecute/PostExecute from Symfony1).

I created a base class from which all the controllers are inherited,
and registered an event listener to run controller's preExecute() method before running requested action, but after reading tons of documentation and questions from here I still can't find how to run postExecute().

*Foo/BarBundle/Controller/BaseController.php:*

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
  protected $_user;
  protected $_em;

  public function preExecute() {
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->_user = $user instanceof User ? $user : null;
    $this->_em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  }

  public function postExecute() {
    $this->_em->flush();
  }
}
```

*Foo/BarBundle/Controller/FooController.php:*

```
class FooController extends BaseController {
  public function indexAction() {
    $this->_user->setName('Eric');
    $this->_em->persist($this->_user);
  }
}
```

*Foo/BarBundle/EventListener/PreExecute.php:*

```
class PreExecute {
  public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
      $controllers = $event->getController();
      if (is_array($controllers)) {
        $controller = $controllers[0];

        if (is_object($controller) && method_exists($controller, 'preExecute')) {
          $controller->preExecute();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a discussion of this [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1975) and this particular example by [schmittjoh](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1975#issuecomment-1829574) may lead you in the right direction.

```
<?php

class Listener
{
    public function onKernelController($event)
    {
        $currentController = $event->getController();
        $newController = function() use ($currentController) {
            // pre-execute
            $rs = call_user_func_array($currentController, func_get_args());
            // post-execute

            return $rs;
        };
        $event->setController($newController);
    }
}
```